# What is the difference between "mental position" and "feeling" or "emotion"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, difference

Some of the meanings of attitude according to Merriam-Webster are:

> a: a **mental position** with regard to a fact or state 
> *a helpful attitude* 
> b: a **feeling or emotion** toward a fact or state a negative attitude 
> *an optimistic attitude*

How does one distinguish a **"mental position"** from a **"feeling or emotion"**?

Comment: The "mental position" need not be emotional – it might be a hard-headed rule-based attitude.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you, sir, but I'm not a native English speaker and I studied only basic English up till college. Could you please explain it with an example?

Comment: If someone does not care about something, that is their mental position. Feelings or emotions may not come into it. Similarly if someone's mental position is that the law has been broken they may have no actual feelings on the matter. That is their attitude.